# how to express big-M formulation as an indicator constraint

Tags: linear-programming

I want to solve the following LP using CPLEX. In the CPLEX documentation it is suggested to use indicator constraint instead of big-M formulation. I searched on google the term "indicator constraints" but except some research papers I could not find much information on this type of constraints.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to convert the big-M equation into an indicator constraint.

**Problem Formulation**
$$ \min \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \sum_{f \in F} c_{ij}^fx^f_{ij}$$

$$ \sum_{j \in V}x^f_{ij} - \sum_{j \in V}x_{ji}^f = \begin{cases}
d_f  &, & i = s_f \\
-d_f&, & i = t_f\\
0 &,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} x_{ij}^f \le u_{ij}$$
$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} w_{i,j}y_{ij}^f \le W^f$$

$$0 \le x^f_{i,j} \le My^f_{i,j}, \,\, y^f_{i,j} \in \{0, 1\} \quad \forall (i,j) \in E, f \in F$$

This is a modified multicommodity flow problem that for a flow $f$ the sum of all the weights $w_{ij}$ of the edges for which $x^f_{i,j} \gt 0$ should be less than $W^f$.

**Solution 1**
$$ \min \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \sum_{f \in F} c_{ij}^fx^f_{ij}$$

$$ \sum_{j \in V}x^f_{ij} - \sum_{j \in V}x_{ji}^f = \begin{cases}
d_f  &, & i = s_f \\
-d_f&, & i = t_f\\
0 &,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} x_{ij}^f \le u_{ij}$$
$$ \sum_{i,j \in E} w_{i,j}y_{ij}^f \le W^f$$
$$ y_{i,j}^f = 0 \Rightarrow x_{i,j}^f = 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in E, f \in F$$

$$ x^f_{i,j} \ge 0, \,\, y^f_{i,j} \in \{0, 1\} \quad \forall (i,j) \in E, f \in F$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indicator constraint is
$$y_{i,j}^f = 0 \Rightarrow x_{i,j}^f = 0 \quad \forall (i,j) \in E, f \in F$$

Comment: Thank you LinAlg. Would you please guide me on  how to add this indicator constraint into my formulation. I have modified my formulation in my question, is this correct?

Comment: @Corey yes, but you should write either $\Rightarrow$ or "if .. then". Use \text in latex for text.

Comment: I removed the "if". LinAlg would you please explain this indicator constraint for me. Since we are saying that if $y^f_{ij}$ is zero then $x^f_{ij}$ should also be zero. I have a bit of doubt on how the solvers know that whether $y^f_{ij}$ is zero or one; as no where in the formulation we are changing the value of $y$

Comment: The solver will optimize $y$ just as in your original formulation. The formulations are equivalent.

Comment: Just one more question, there is no need to add $y$ to the objective function?

Comment: @Corey that's right.